# automaticaly implemented fields in other languages

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texstudio, overleaf, languages

I need to cite an online resource using this syntax:

```
@InCollection{crisp,
    title     = {The CRISP-DM reference model},
    booktitle = {Crisp-Dm 1.0},
    address    = {США},
    date      = {1999},
    url       = {https://web.archive.org/web/20220401041957/https://www.the-modeling-agency.com/crisp-dm.pdf},
    urldate   = {2022-10-02},
    language  = {russian},
}
```

The point is to receive the correct result on the part of url and urldate ("Режим обращения"=Access mode and "Дата обращения"="accessed") that is automaticaly implemented. It works on tex studio but on the overleaf I get a sequence of symbols. I have uft8, babel, T2A, but it doesn't work. Can you help me pls? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the set up of your document (not just your bib file). There a various ways how to set up a bibliopgraphy and it is therefore crucial that you post more information about this. Unrelated: I highly doubt that "Дата обращения" means both "Access mode" and "accessed".

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I added the wrong one - Access mode = Режим обращения.

Comment: You can use the Edit link below the question to add additional information or correct things.

Comment: thx - done! Unfortunately, I didn't understand how to do it but I'll try to deal with it :)

Comment: I think there are some overeleaf's settings because on tex studio it runs :(

Comment: Did you check whether you use the same compiler? You can change the compiler in the menu on Overleaf. Do you get any warnings or errors?

Comment: If you can show us a small example document (and not just the code of your `.bib` entry), we can try to investigate what is going on here. Normally, `biblatex` should adapt its output to the document language (if `biblatex` speaks the relevant language, which is the case for Russian). The MWE at https://gist.github.com/moewew/8e79efdde1bf74c8e3b5547d626c91ca compiles fine for me both locally and on Overleaf (w/ TeX live 2022) and produces "дата обр.".

Answer (score 1):

TeXstudio and Overleaf are just sophisticated graphical user interfaces for

- typing/editing/saving .tex-input-files.
- calling programs that belong to a TeX distribution for processing/compiling the .tex-input-files.

The programs of the TeX distribution can also be called from the command-line/shell-prompt/console-prompt if you have access to a command-line/shell-prompt/console-prompt for running programs on the system where the TeX distribution is installed.

With Overleaf the TeX distribution is not installed on your local machine but it is installed on the servers of Overleaf/Digital Science & Research Solutions Ltd. With Overleaf you don't have direct access via command-line/shell-prompt/console-prompt to the programs that belong to the TeX distribution. When Overleaf's "online LaTeX and Rich Text collaborative writing and publishing tool" is running in your internet browser, then that tool accesses/calls these programs for you, e.g., as soon as you click the "Recompile"-button while working on a .tex-input-file.

---

In order to know what happens one needs to know about the TeX-distribution (release/version etc) and probably the operation system in use. .log-files of the actual TeX-run might be useful here.

(Overleaf provides this information when clicking near the "Recompile"-button on the symbol for "Logs and output files" and selecting "raw logs". )

As you did not yet provide any piece of information useful for doing a diagnosis and as I don't have a crystal ball ;-) , I can only do a blind guess.

In order to explain that blind guess I first need to tell some facts about LaTeX:

- LaTeX can be considered a huge collection of macros which is loaded to a TeX-compiler. Nowadays TeX-compilers can be, e.g.,

  - Donald Ervin Knuth's traditional TeX-engine
  - Hàn Thế Thành's pdfTeX-engine
  - XeTeX (by Jonathan Kew and Arthur Rosendahl)
  - LuaTeX by the LuaTeX Team (Hans Hagen, Hartmut Henkel, Taco Hoekwater, Luigi Scarso).

  In the past reading/loading huge collections of macros into a TeX compiler and hereby doing all the macro-assignments etc took a considerable amount of time. So the habit became established to create/dump a memory image of the state the TeX program was in right after loading the macro collection and henceforth to load this memory image directly. This way the program/compiler and the macro collection were available in one go which was faster than first loading the TeX-program/compiler and then running it and then loading the huge macro collection.
- If the "LaTeX-compiler" in use is based on XeTeX (XeLaTeX) or LuaTeX (LuaLaTeX), then the underlying TeX-engine a priori/from the outset "assumes" that characters of input-files are encoded in the multibyte-encoding "utf8".
- If the "LaTeX-compiler" in use is based on Donald E. Knuth's traditional TeX-engine (LaTeX) or on Hàn Thế Thành's pdfTeX-engine (pdfLaTeX), then the underlying TeX-engine "assumes" that characters of .tex-input-files are encoded in some 8bit/single-byte-input-encoding (whereof with TeX-distributions MiKTeX and TeX Live 7-bit-ASCII, i.e. bytes 0(decimal) to 127(decimal) denoting code-points for characters according to the American Standard Code for Information Interchange, is to be a subset).
  If with such an 8-bit-engine/"single-byte-character-engine" a .tex-input-file is not encoded in ASCII/iso8859-1(latin1)/cp1252/whatever single-byte-encoding but is encoded in the multibyte-encoding utf-8, then the package inputenc needs to be loaded with the option "utf8" for things to (probably) work out.
  If that package is not loaded with that option while with such engines attempting to process utf-8-encoded .tex-input-files, then not combinations of bytes are assumed to form single characters but each single byte is taken for a single character on its own which leads to TeX displaying unexpected sequences of graphemes/symbols.

  Nowadays with compilers based on these traditional 8-bit/single-byte-character-TeX-engines support for .tex-input-files being encoded in unicode is enabled in LaTeX by default by automatically loading the package inputenc with the option "utf8" when after processing the preamble LaTeX detects that the package inputenc has not already been loaded with other options.

  But this is not the case with older versions/releases of TeX Live and MiKTeX. Thus if using LaTeX based on a traditional 8-bit/single-byte-character-TeX-engine on an older TeX-platform/TeX-distribution for processing a .tex-input-file which is encoded in utf-8 and which contains characters outside the range of ASCII (ASCII is a strict subset of utf-8), then the package inputenc needs to be loaded in the preamble explicitly.

Therefore I guess that when working via the Overleaf-site an older TeX Live distribution is in use where unicode support is not enabled by default.

As far as I know Overleaf under the hood loads a container with a docker-image of some minimal Linux-installation where some TeX Live distribution is installed.

After clicking the "Menu"-button in the top-left-corner of the browser-window where the Overleaf-site is displayed, a side-bar opens up, where beneath many other things you can select items like "Compiler" and "TeX Live version".

Probably pdflatex or latex, based on traditional 8-bit-TeX is selected and as "TeX Live version" some legacy release is selected where with pdflatex/latex unicode-support by automatically loading the package inputenc with option utf8 is not provided yet so that you'd need to add something to the preamble of your document like `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Probably as compiler you can select XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (which are native utf8-engines) and/or select the most recent TeX Live Version, 2022, where with pdflatex or latex, based on traditional 8-bit-TeX, the automatic loading of the package inputenc with option utf8 is provided.

Maybe with the machine where TeX Studio is used for typing the .tex-input-files a recent TeX distribution, e.g., TeX Live release 2020 or 2021 or 2022) or MiKTeX 22.<whatsoever month>.<whatsoever day> is in use so that with any latex compiler utf8-support is provided by default. (With LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX the underlying TeX-engine "natively" from the outset "assumes" that .tex-input-files are encoded in utf-8. With traditional LaTeX/pdfLaTeX the inputenc-package is loaded with the option "utf8" automatically after processing the preamble if the inputenc has not been loaded otherwise in the preamble.)